# Running 2 stored procedures in post SQL for Informatica

Tags: stored-procedures, informatica

I will like to run two stored procedures in the post session SQL command of Informatica for one of my workflow.

My current code is:

```
BEGIN
    STORED_PROCEDURE_1
    STORED PROCEDURE_2
END;
```

When I ran the workflow, it seemed like this syntax is not correct. Will need some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: can you pls use stored proc transformation or sql transformation? End each proc using semicolon(;)

Comment: Did you get any error?